# Setting up a basic signal receiver in the sandbox app

Tags: django-oscar

I'm trying to set up a signal receiver in the sandbox app. I created `/sandbox/signals/receivers.py` with the following code:

```
import logging

from django.dispatch import receiver
from oscar.apps.catalogue.signals import product_viewed


@receiver(product_viewed)
def receive_product_view(sender, product, user, **kwargs):
    logging.info("receive_product_view")
    if user and user.is_authenticated:
        logging.info("Product {product} viewed by user {user}")
    else:
        logging.info("Product {product} viewed anonymously")
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. In `/sandbox/__init__.py` I do `import signals` and I have `/sandbox/signals/__init__.py` which does `import receivers` so I'm assuming it loads that module on startup (this could be a bad assumption).

When I load a product page in the browser, I don't see anything in the console log. Could I just have logging set up wrong, or this the wrong way to wire up signal receivers?

Answer (score 0):

The Django docs recommend that you import your signal receivers from inside the `ready()` [method of your application configuration class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver). [Here is an example](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/apps.py#L17) of how Oscar itself does this.

Importing the receiver where you're currently doing it is I suspect not going to work at all - `sandbox` is not loaded as a module in its own right, it's just a directory that houses other modules.

The sandbox that ships with Oscar doesn't have any of its own apps that you could add this to - so you'd need to add one to the `apps` directory and then include that in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.